# automatically play sounds on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, mp3, autoplay

For a project, I have to play a sound when the scroll is finished. But on IOS devices autoplay is disabled. I didn't find any affordable solution to automatically play the sound. Creating a fake click didn't work, I guess the get this is not a real click.

Any solution ?

Thnak's for your help

Comment: You have `scroll` event to play with..

Comment: It doesn't work. I read on many website that a sound can be played only with an event. The only one that works is "click", scroll, touch etc don't work.